# Docker unknown flag: --network

Tags: docker

I want to share my host with container.

I already have some services running in containers, e.g. Redis.

I want to run another app in another container. The app expects that Redis is listening on localhost:6379.

From my host machine, I have an access to that port, because I have a port mapping from the Redis-container port to the host port.

I want my app container to have access to the same ports and networks that my host machine has.

I tried this command: `docker --network=host run somecontainer` but got `unknown flag: --network` so no success. [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach), [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-host).

How else I can achieve the behavior described above? Host localhost = container localhost

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You inverted the parameters and docker is trying to resolve the flag when no command is given (you can see with `docker --help` that `--network` is not listed)

`docker run --network ...` will work better! :-)

Don't forget that `--network` is a flag for the `run` command, `run` must precede.

TLDR: `docker run --help` and `docker --help` are different, errors happen.

Comment: Oh, comon!... :D